# PHP file size validation for contact form with attachment

Tags: php, filesize

I've made contact form with `php`, and validation for name, email and message works great, but my file size validation doesn't work. When I try to upload file larger then 2 MB it's loading and collapse. 
I've run out of ideas what to do. Can anyone help me?
Here is my `php` code:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {

        if (!$_POST['name']){
            $error="Unesite svoje ime.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
            $error.="Unesite e-mail adresu.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $error.="Unesite tekst poruke";
        }
        if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error.="Unesite validu e-mail adresu.";
        }

        if(!empty($_FILES['my-file']['name'])){
            $file_name = $_FILES['my-file']['name'];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['my-file']['type'];

            if($_FILES['my-file']['size'] > 524288){
                $error.="Maksimalna velicina fajla je 5 MB.";
            } else {

            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $to = "nicolletta.dj@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Poruka sa sajta";
            $message = "Tekst poruke:".$_POST['message'];

            $file = $temp_name;
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
            $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

            $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $header .= "From:".$from."\r\n"; 
            $header .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']."" . "\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

            //plain text part
            $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
            //attachment part
            $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

            if ($error) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>';
            } else {
                if (mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Vasa poruka je poslata!</strong></div>';} 
                else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Došlo je do greške prilikom slanja poruke. Molim Vas pokušajte ponovo kasnije.</div>';}
    } //if there is no error
        }} else {if ($error) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>';
            } else {
                $header = "From:".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
                $header = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']. "\n" ;
                $body = "Tekst poruke:".$_POST['message'];

                if (mail('nicolletta.dj@gmail.com', 'Poruka sa sajta', $body, $header)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Vasa poruka je poslata!</strong></div>';} 
                else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Došlo je do greške prilikom slanja poruke. Molim Vas pokušajte ponovo kasnije.</div>';}
    }}//if files not empty
    } //if is submited
?>
```

and my `HTML` code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 emailForm">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
    <form id="contact_body" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Ime i prezime:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ime i prezime" data-required="true"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" data-required="true"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Poruka:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" data-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="file" name="my-file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name);">
                    Dodajte sliku
            </label>
            <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="push" class="pushbutton"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg" value="Poslati"/>         
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `if($_FILES['my-file']['size'] > '524288')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get error - because you have set lower value for php upload setting:

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

```
post_max_size = 40M
```

If you reach this limits - the file is not uploaded and **$_FILES[..][error]!=0.**

And the second - **524288 is not 5MB but only 524kB**

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen that missing zero. Even though, it still doesn't working. Even if I don't change values for php upload settings and just put this code:
if($_FILES['my-file']['size'] > '2097152' ) {$error.="Please add files smaller than 2 MB."; }       it still doesn't working. I'm totally new and lost in this.

Comment: As i said: you need to increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size at your php.ini file :-) Then you can upload file largest than 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

add a zero

```
if($_FILES['my-file']['size'] > 5242880)
```